# Making a geographical query on PostGIS using Superset

Tags: postgis, apache-superset

I'm currently using Apache Superset, over a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS, for my website, but a use case came up that I can't seem to find a solution using this tool.

I have events that have an associated location, and my website allows users to create custom regions that could be used as filters in Superset (i.e. they can filter events so only those within the custom region show up).

I can easily do this with SQL, using PostGIS method `ST_WITHIN` but there doesn't seem to be a way to this dynamically within Superset.

Another idea I had was to calculate this beforehand, by adding an array field to the event table, that would contain all the custom regions they belong to. When a user creates a region, a task would run to see which events belong to that region and add the region to the event array. Now, apart from not scaling very well, Superset also doesn't seem to be able to filter on array lists (it interprets them as a single string).

Any ideas on working around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jinja templating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blhWKmxkIHE&t=95s) to filter by elements of an array